# NCO, Library not loaded

Tags: path, nco

I am trying to run the NCO executable ncks in the terminal window. I found that I needed to create a .bashrc file to initially get started in addition to installing NCO from MacPorts. Now when I run ncks I get this error.

```
dhcp-v219-194:~ mlaf$ ncks
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssh2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/matthewlaffin/anaconda/bin/ncks
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I am new to terminal and NCO but I have read that there could be an error in the path name which results in NCO not being able to find the Library. Does anyone have any insight into how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from (ana)conda, not from MacPorts, because the `ncks` executable `/Users/matthewlaffin/anaconda/bin/ncks` is in your (ana)conda directory, and it is trying to find an (ana)conda library that apparently not installed. Not sure why. See [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4421#issuecomment-327033866) issue for a possible solution.

If you did not have (ana)conda installed, then presumably your default NCO would be from MacPorts, and the MacPorts installation works so long as your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are correctly set.

Comment: Looks like I did not update my PATH in .bashrc and .bash_profile. Thanks for your help Charlie.